# Php Mailer is not sending Mails

Tags: php, email, ssl, phpmailer

I am trying to send email from `mochahost` server. I am using `PhpMailer`and `Gmail SMTP` to send Email. I have understand all the settings of `php mailer` and put them correctly, but its still giving me error messages, and not sending `mails`.

Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here.

```
<?php

    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'senderemail@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = ' My Name';
$mail->addAddress('userEmail@Hotmail.com', ' User Name');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('tahakirmani@Hotmail.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('taha.kirmani88@gmail.com');
//$mail->addBCC('taha.kirmani88@gmail.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}



?>
```

**ERROR**

```
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: If you enable verbose output do you get a more descriptive error message?

Comment: Detailed Error message ... http://ivsapps.com/mailer_test/mail.php

Comment: I know it night seem like a radical idea, but you could try [reading the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) or any of the many duplicates of this question.